# create utf-8 text file from a sas datastep

Tags: json, encoding, utf-8, sas, datastep

I have this macro that creates a json file,
but even though I have specified `encoding='utf-8' bom` I don't get an utf-8 file.

```
%macro json4datatables_useformat(ds,path,file,charvars,numvars)
    / 
    DES="json4datatables(ds,path,file,charvars,numvars)";

    /* creates a json with no headers
     * a bit like a csv without the first line
     * it takes thus less space
     * but you have to know which column is what
     */

    data _null_;
        length line $300;
        set &ds nobs=nobs end=end;
        file "&path.&file." encoding='utf-8' bom/**/ ;

        line = '[';

        %if &charvars ne %then %do;
            %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&charvars));
                %let charvar = %scan(&charvars, &i);
                %if &i ne 1 %then %do;
                    line = cats(line,',');
                %end;
                line = cats(line,'"',vvalue(&charvar),'"');
            %end;
        %end;
        %if &numvars ne %then %do;
            %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&numvars));
                %let numvar = %scan(&numvars, &i);
                line = catx(',',line,vvalue(&numvar));
            %end;
        %end;

        line = cats(line,']');

        if _n_=1 then put '{"data": [';
        if not end then put line +(-1) ',';
        else do;
            put line;
            put ']}';
        end;
        run;

%mend json4datatables_useformat;
```

I noticed because accents appear as strange charactes on the web page where I display the json file.
And the issue is solved simply by opening the json file in sublime text and doing **File>Save with Encoding>UTF-8**. 
(with BOM isn't necessary.)

Is there another way to force utf-8 encoding?

EDIT: I'm using SAS EG 7.1 , SAS 9.3 on windows.

Comment: I used your macro and exported data with some polish caracters. Notepad++ says that it is UTF8 and Chrome browser displays all characters properly. What is your SAS version?

Comment: I guess this means it's probably system-related

Comment: What encoding is your SAS session using?  It shouldn't matter, in theory, but I find sometimes it helps to be in a UTF-8 session instead of an ANSI session.  Also, what version of SAS are you running?

Comment: How can I find the encoding of the SAS session? I'm using SAS EG 7.1 , SAS 9.3 on windows.

Comment: Hmm, 9.3 should be good enough.  The encoding of the SAS session in EG is visible by right clicking on the name of the server in the Server List (if it's local, then Local is the server) and selecting properties, then software tab (only visible if open).  That lists the encoding.

Comment: SAS Session Encoding: __wlatin1__.  If you know how to change that I would glandly try it. (will be back in 10 days)

Comment: @ooo If it's local SAS then you can change it by changing the EG settings as to what it connects to; easiest way I *think* is to change the file in `\SASFoundation\9.3\sasv9.cfg` to point to the one in `\nls\u8` instead of `\nls\en\` (I think EG will respect that).  If it's a server, you'll have to talk to your server admin.

Comment: I had no problems with this having wlatin2 session and writing to utf8. It is something else. If I get something I will let you know. BTW nice macro :)

Answer (score 0):

Your browser doesn't have the appropriate character set and / or fonts to render your data.

To add the language you want to browse:

Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Keyboards and Languages -> Display language -> Install/uninstall languages